# JQuery UI snapping to a grid within an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have two divs, and I'm using the JQueryUI library to drop one div into another.

I want to snap the draggable div to a grid within the drop div rather than a grid across the entire page.  I have found the snap attribute to snap to the drop element, I've also found the grid attribute to snap it to a grid but is there any way to combine the two?

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ grid: [ 50, 50 ] });
```

The only other workaround I can think about are to populate the drop div with lots of smaller snap divs which is an approach I don't like!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the droppable's over and out methods to detect when the draggable was over it, and then implement the grid parameter only at that point.

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
$("#snaptarget").droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $("#draggable").draggable({
            grid: [50, 50]
        });
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $("#draggable").draggable("option", "grid", false);
    }
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mAzLA/1/)**.

Comment: That's right. False is the default value for the grid, so by setting to back to false after 50,50, you're essentially resetting that option.